# How to create a new mongodb instance on the same box as an old broken instance

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo instance that was running but fails with an error

```
[ftdc] Uncaught exception in 'FileRenameFailed: File exists' in full-time diagnosti
c data capture subsystem. Shutting down the full-time diagnostic data capture subsystem.

 STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger error (17), file:Wir
edTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /my/mongodb/path/WiredTiger.turtle.set to /my/mongodb/path/WiredTiger.turtle: file-rename: rename: File exists

STORAGE  [thread2] WiredTiger error (0), file:Wir
edTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: WiredTiger.turtle: encountered an illegal file format or internal value
```

So I understand there is something wrong with the WiredTiger.turtle file. I want to create a fresh new database instance. But if I point the --dbpath to a completely different directory ie --dbpath /some/new/directory/ I get the same error.

So does mongo store state in some other place?

If I do a clean mongo install on a different box it works. So there has to be some file I need to remove in addition to changing the dbpath, but I'm not sure where. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
This turned out to be something specific to the /some/new/directory/ I was trying to write to. That volume was configured for archiving. The volume is writable, and Mongo does fail with the above exception, so there is something weird happening. However I pointed mongo to a non archive drive and everything worked.

Comment: Does the "same error" complines about the .turtle file in the "/some/new/directory" ? Which version of the DB you are using?

Comment: Yes, mongo logs the exact same lines. We are using version 3.4.9. I noticed that I only see this error when the path is on a particular mount. So it may turn out to be something specific to that drive that mongo doesnt like. We are still investigating.

Comment: MongoDB requires a POSIX compliant filesystem to operate correctly. Is `/my/mongodb/path` mounted on a local disk or is it a network disk?

Comment: It is not local, it is mount to a networked drive. We have several mounts on this particular box. One of them works fine (also network drive), another does not. I'll have to check if they are both POSIX compliant. That may be the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to tell the whole story since the setup is rather not typical. And it would be better to do it on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AlexBlex you are right. Dba exchange is probably better. I'll use that in the future.